# Rendering a partial being passed through JSON, using gMap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm using gMap (http://gmap.nurtext.de/) to display map data in a Rails app. The way it works is you pass it JSON markers containing variables, and it renders them on a Google Map. When you click on a marker it shows the HTML contained in the variable 'html'.

It works fine, but at the moment I'm passing html in the JSON from the model. This annoys me because that html should be in a view. I'd like to somehow pass a partial in the JSON which is then rendered in the html.

At the moment the json is created, in the model, with this code

```
def as_json(options={})

    hash = Hash.new
    hash[:longitude] = longitude.to_i
    hash[:latitude] = latitude.to_i
    hash[:html] = "<p>#{title}</p>"
    hash[:popup] = true
    hash[:url] = "/listings/"+id.to_s

    return hash    
end
```

The :html key is where I'd like to put something like

```
hash[:html] = "<%= render :partial => "listings/bubble", :locals => {:listing => @listings.first} %>"
```

The partial works on its own - I've put it straight in a view to check. The pop up bubble also works when you have straight html in the JSON.

However when the partial is passed inside the JSON the resulting code is

```
<div class="gmap_marker">
    <%= render :partial => "listings/bubble", :locals => {:listing => @listings.first} %>
</div>
```

It just ends up as a string in the HTML, it's never rendered.

So I guess there are two options I'm looking for:

1. The partial is rendered before it is passed as JSON (e.g. at the model end)
   or
2. The partial is rendered when the view is rendered.

Not sure if this is a javascript question or a Rails question, but any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right idea, but you have to use the [**render_to_string**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) function:

```
hash[:html] = render_to_string(:partial => "listings/bubble", 
    :locals => {:listing => @listings.first})
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's giving me the following error:
`NoMethodError in ListingsController#index undefined method `render_to_string' for #<Listing:0x1031cda00>`

Comment: (Ah, I see I need to mention you @DR before you can see my reply)

Comment: That's weird. It seems that Ruby tries to call `Listing.render_to_string` which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't notice you are calling this from your model. `render_to_string` is only available from a controller.